# Updating a tri-match pandas script to update instead of append columns

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, pandas

I'm looking for some help updating my python script to "match" with pandas instead of creating new columns... I've added all the details below aswell as the incorrect and correct outcomes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

#### `test.csv` (Original CSV File)

```
MATCH1,MATCH2,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,MATCH3,DATA,TITLE,TITLE
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Tommy,55,data,data
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Ben,54,data,data
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jim,52,data,data
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Elz M,22,data,data
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,James Smith,15,data,data
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jessica Long,224,data,data
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Mike,62,data,data
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Joe Reane,66,data,data
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Peter Jones,256,data,data
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Lesley Lope,5226,data,data
```

#### `test.txt` (Original Text File)

```
MData (N/A)
DMATCH1
3 Tommy 144512/23332
1 Jim 90000/222311
1 Elz M 90000/222311
1 Ben 90000/222311
Data $50.90
misc2 $10.40
bla3 $20.20


MData (B/B) 
DMATCH2
4 James Smith 2333/114441
4 Mike 90000/222311
4 Jessica Long 2333/114441
Data $50.90
bla3 $5.44
```

#### `Test.py` (Run me)

```
import re
import pandas
# each block in the text file will be one element of this list
matchers = [[]]
i = 0 
with open('test.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        # Blocks are seperated by blank lines
        if len(line) == 0:
            i += 1
            matchers.append([])
            # assume there are always two blank lines between items 
            # and just skip to the lext line
            infile.next()
            continue
        matchers[i].append(line)


# This regular expression matches the variable number of students in each block
studentlike = re.compile('(\d+) (.+) (\d+/\d+)')
# These are the names of the fields we expect at the end of each block
datanames = ['Data', 'misc2', 'bla3']
# We will build a table containing a list of elements for each student
table = []
for matcher in matchers:
    # We use an iterator over the block lines to make indexing simpler
    it = iter(matcher)
    # The first two elements are match values
    m1, m2 = it.next(), it.next()
    # then there are a number of students
    students = []
    for possiblestudent in it:
        m = studentlike.match(possiblestudent)
        if m:
            students.append(list(m.groups()))
        else:
            break
    # After the students come the data elements, which we read into a dictionary
    # We also add in the last possible student line as that didn't match the student re
    dataitems = dict(item.split() for item in [possiblestudent] + list(it))
    # Finally we construct the table
    for student in students:
        # We use the dictionary .get() method to return blanks for the missing fields
        table.append([m1, m2] + student + [dataitems.get(d, '') for d in datanames])


csvdata = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
textdata = pandas.DataFrame(table, columns=['MATCH2', 'MATCH1', 'TITLE01', 'MATCH3', 'TITLE02', 'Data', 'misc2', 'bla3'])
mergeddata = pandas.merge(csvdata, textdata, how='left', on=['MATCH1', 'MATCH2', 'MATCH3'], sort=False)
mergeddata.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

#### `test.csv` (Updated CSV File after `test.py` has been ran)

```
MATCH1,MATCH2,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,MATCH3,DATA,TITLE,TITLE,,,,,
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Tommy,55,data,data,3,144512/23332,Data $50.90,misc2 $10.40,bla3 $20.20
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Ben,54,data,data,1,90000/222311,,,
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jim,52,data,data,1,90000/222311,,,
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Elz M,22,data,data,1,90000/222311,,,
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,James Smith,15,data,data,4,2333/114441,Data $50.90,,bla3 $5.44
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jessica Long,224,data,data,4,2333/114441,,,
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Mike,62,data,data,4,90000/222311,,,
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Joe Reane,66,data,data,,,,,
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Peter Jones,256,data,data,,,,,
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Lesley Lope,5226,data,data,,,,,
```

#### `test.txt` (Updated text file)

```
Mdata
DMATCH3
5 Joe Reane 0/0
5 Peter Jones 90000/222311
Data $10.91
misc2 $420.00
bla3 $210.00
```

#### As the text file has been updated we need to re-run `test.py` and this will output the incorrect/wrong following: `test.csv` (Updated)

```
MATCH1,MATCH2,TITLE,TITLE.1,TITLE.2,TITLE.3,TITLE.4,TITLE.5,MATCH3,DATA,TITLE.6,TITLE.7,TITLE01_x,TITLE02_x,Data_x,misc2_x,bla3_x,TITLE01_y,TITLE02_y,Data_y,misc2_y,bla3_y
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Tommy,55,data,data,3.0,144512/23332,$50.90,$10.40,$20.20,3,144512/23332,$50.90,$10.40,$20.20
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Ben,54,data,data,1.0,90000/222311,$50.90,$10.40,$20.20,1,90000/222311,$50.90,$10.40,$20.20
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jim,52,data,data,1.0,90000/222311,$50.90,$10.40,$20.20,1,90000/222311,$50.90,$10.40,$20.20
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Elz M,22,data,data,1.0,90000/222311,$50.90,$10.40,$20.20,1,90000/222311,$50.90,$10.40,$20.20
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,James Smith,15,data,data,4.0,2333/114441,$50.90,,$5.44,4,2333/114441,$50.90,,$5.44
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jessica Long,224,data,data,4.0,2333/114441,$50.90,,$5.44,4,2333/114441,$50.90,,$5.44
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Mike,62,data,data,4.0,90000/222311,$50.90,,$5.44,4,90000/222311,$50.90,,$5.44
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Joe Reane,66,data,data,,,,,,,,,,
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Peter Jones,256,data,data,,,,,,,,,,
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Lesley Lope,5226,data,data,,,,,,,,,,
```

#### The correct output should of been an updated file: `test.csv`

```
MATCH1,MATCH2,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,MATCH3,DATA,TITLE,TITLE,,,,,
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Tommy,55,data,data,3,144512/23332,Data $50.90,misc2 $10.40,bla3 $20.20
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Ben,54,data,data,1,90000/222311,,,
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jim,52,data,data,1,90000/222311,,,
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Elz M,22,data,data,1,90000/222311,,,
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,James Smith,15,data,data,4,2333/114441,Data $50.90,,bla3 $5.44
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jessica Long,224,data,data,4,2333/114441,,,
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Mike,62,data,data,4,90000/222311,,,
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Joe Reane,66,data,data,5,0/0,,misc2 $420.00,bla3 $210.00
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Peter Jones,256,data,data,5,90000/222311,,,
DMATCH3,Mdata,data,data,data,data,data,data,Lesley Lope,5226,data,data,,,,,
```

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

---

### Traceback Error for jsexauer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 62, in <module>
    mergeddata = pandas.merge(csvdata, textdata, how='right', on=mergecols, sort=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 37, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 197, in get_result
    self._maybe_add_join_keys(result, left_indexer, right_indexer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 222, in _maybe_add_join_keys
    right_na_indexer))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Ok, now I think maybe I see what you're going for.  I think you want to use the [`update` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns)  Does this give you what you're looking for?

```
textcols = ['MATCH2', 'MATCH1', 'TITLE01', 'MATCH3', 'TITLE02', 'Data', 'misc2', 'bla3']
csvdata = pandas.read_csv(CSV_IN)
textdata = pandas.DataFrame(table, columns=textcols)

# Add any new columns
newCols = textdata.columns - csvdata.columns
for c in newCols:
    csvdata[c] = None

mergecols = ['MATCH2', 'MATCH1', 'MATCH3']
csvdata.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True, drop=False)
textdata.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True,drop=False)
csvdata.update(textdata)
csvdata.to_csv(CSV_OUT, index=False)
```

Comment: Similar but it needs to overwrite values if there is already data in that matched cells

Comment: I think you can achieve that by changing the merge to `how='right'`.

Comment: I've edited my original post to show the error after using how='right'

Comment: Updated to take care of that.